# Android : How to hide the Activity without using finish

Tags: android

I'am just calling an Activity from the BroadCastReceiver. So when the phone is `Ringing` it will show the Activty. My problem is when I use my application then if i get a call means then the current Activity is not hiding.

So I cannot see the calling screen and I cannot pick the call. Whatever the activity I have opened, Just I want to hide when the call is coming and again I want to show the same Activity.

Before that I have used finish method in the onReceive method. But if I use that then next time it is not calling the BroadCastReceiver.

Instead of this code what I can write to hide all my Activities.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    LoginActivity.context.finish();
    MainAtivity.context.finish();
    ProjectActivity.context.finish();
    telephonyRegister(context,intent);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in your activity.

```
  @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: @prshntjjlYeah. I tried this. But still the activity is not hiding.